# VoIP: No ringback on specific provider combination

Tags: voip, sip, telephony

please help me out with this one:

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

1. No ringback when calling cellphones using VoWIFI/VoLTE
2. Only happens when calling from a specific VoIP telephony provider to a specific cellphone provider (with VoWIFI/VoLTE enabled)
3. Call goes through even though there is no ringback so if you don't hang up the person on the other end will pick it up
4. Tested on Grandstream devices and softphones so it doesn't seem to be a hardware problem

**QUESTIONS**

1. What are some common causes for no ringback? I know it's related to 180 ringing message so could it be that the provider does not actually relay those 180 sip messages (e.g., because of a firewall configuration)? Then again, why do I get ringback when I call cellphones registered to another provider? Have they stopped relaying sip 180 only when it comes from a particular provider? Would that make any sense?
2. Is there any workaround that would allow me to generate some sort of "fake" ringback? I got many complaints from people that calls don't go through and I have to explain the whole situation and prove to them that calls do indeed go through even though there is no sound. This is particularly prominent amongst elderly people.

**TL;DR**

VoIP providers: x,y,z

Cellphone providers: a,b,c

x -> a(VoWIFI/VoLTE) = no ringback + call goes through

x -> b/c(VoWIFI/VoLTE) = ringback + call goes through

y/z -> a/b/c(VoWIFI/VoLTE) = ringback + call goes through

x/y/z -> a/b/c(no VoWIFI/VoLTE) = ringback + call goes through

Thanks!

Comment: And there is also no SIP/183 reply with early media session, maybe some announcement or audio ringback signal?